# Can't Update Field in Advanced Custom Field From APi

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I pulled some data from a XML API in wordpress. The code can create custom post according to the data from the API. But when I try to update fields from that API it does not update. I am using Advanced Custom Fields plugin. Any help would be wonderful.
Here, is the code

```
  register_post_type( 'hotels', array(
    'label' => 'Hotels',
    'public' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
  ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_hotels' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_hotels_from_api', 'get_hotels_from_api' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_hotels_from_api', 'get_hotels_from_api' );
function get_hotels_from_api() {
    $files = glob("/home/u952383080/domains/expertsecuritiesbd.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/themify-shoppe/API/*xml");
      $hotels = [];
      $current_page = ( ! empty( $_POST['current_page'] ) ) ? $_POST['current_page'] : 1;
  if (is_array($files)) {
     foreach($files as $filename) {
        $xml_file = file_get_contents($filename, FILE_TEXT);
        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_file);
        $hotel_slug = sanitize_title($xml->Name."-".$xml->Id);
        echo $xml->Name;
        $id = wp_insert_post( [
        'post_name' => $hotel_slug,
        'post_title' => $hotel_slug,
        'post_type' => 'hotelxian',
        'post_status' => 'publish'
        ]);  
$field_key = "field_5ed8c3f25efc0";
        update_field( $field_key, $xml->Name,$id);
        }
     }
     $current_page = $current_page + 1;

  wp_remote_post( admin_url('admin-ajax.php?action=get_hotels_from_api'), [
    'blocking' => false,
    'sslverify' => false, // we are sending this to ourselves, so trust it.
    'body' => [
      'current_page' => $current_page
    ]
  ] );


}
```

Answer (score 0):

`wp_insert_post()` returns a WP_Post Object. That means that your `$id` is not only the ID. You need to access the ID inside the object to use it in `update_field()`.

In your case it would look like:

```
update_field( $field_key, $xml->Name,$id->ID);
```

btw: Maybe you should rename your `$id` variable to something like `$post` to avoid confusion.